# Comodo AntiVirus for Linux cannot be installed (unmet dependency)

Tags: package-management, dependencies, antivirus

I use Ubuntu Studio 20.04.1 LTS (64 bits Linux).

I downloaded and tried to install the last available version of COMODO AntiVirus for Linux, from its official page, but it cannot to be installed because the following reason:

```
Cannot to satisfied the dependency: libssl0.9.8 (>=0.9.8m-1)
```

Can we fix this issue?

How?

If it is not possible to fix this...

Is there some real-time action AntiVirus for Linux 64 bits?

It is intended to have a real-time protection always running (because ClamAV just works when we ask that from the app, not in real-time mode).

Comment: Do you really want to use that *old* product? It's uses depreciated `libssl` which isn't available for *modern* releases as they're using later & more secure versions.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libssl

Comment: Agreed. It's ironic but you're actually adding a risk when you install an AV because you're essentially opening a back door into processes that normally would require root privileges. A lot has changed in the security landscape since consumer AV software was more necessary.  These days you're better off just to keep your OS up-to-date and don't use unofficial software unless it's sandboxed.

Comment: Virus protection for GNU/Linux isn't really aimed at protecting the Linux user, but rather the windows users who are using files on the GNU/Linux servers, or if files are transferred to windows users later. Malware exists for both worlds yes, but *virus* is almost exclusively a windows issue; and in the end user-behavior is the best protection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear ideas, guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can download the latest libssl which is 1.1.1 from
http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1h-1_amd64.deb, and install it in the normal way using dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1h-1_amd64.deb